# Are 1.8.3 Neo4j typical queries compatible with Cypher 1.9?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am moving a neo4j app (written in node.js) which was originally built for Neo4j 1.8.3 to current version 2.1.5.  Motivation for this is that I had trouble using the webadmin in 1.8.3 and was advised to migrate to 2.1.5.  I was able to successfully install 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 (on linode vm), and following the instructions, was able to convert the database from the old store format to the current one.  Before testing, I am planning to set the cypher_parser_version to 1.9 (the oldest available in 2.1.5) to increase the chances of compatibility.

I've read the list of changes in Cypher from 1.9 to 2.0.  Looking at refcard for 1.9:
http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/1.9/
I don't see any corresponding changes from 1.8 to 1.9

Is there any likelihood that the app might use query syntax that won't be compatible with Parser version  1.9?  Any common issues to look for?

Comment: Curious, but if you're moving from 1.8.3 -> 2.1.5, what do the differences between 1.8.3 and 1.9 matter?  I don't actually know what they are - but I do know that post 2.0 there were several changes (big important things like labels, and much less use of `START` now).

Comment: The idea is that the queries in the app were written against the Cypher 1.8 parser.  They aren't likely to be compatible with the 2.0 parser (from what I've read) so I will set the 1.9 parser as the default.  I was just wondering if the existing queries would be likely to work against the 1.9 parser.  Anyway I'm about to do a test so will report my results to resolve the matter to some extent.

Comment: Initially app seems to work with the 1.9 parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since 1.9 so I don't remember breaking changes by heart. Since the version jump is only on minor level, I don't expect any breaking changes.

However 1.9 comes with certain deprecations, some of them resulted in removal of the mentioned stuff in the 2.x series, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.8/deprecations.html for details.

It's best practice to have a valid test case for each of your queries, so you'll detect incompatibilities upon upgrades immediately.